# AWS VPC CIDRs in both 10.0.0.0/8 and 192.168.0.0/16

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, vpc-peering

I have VPC A with CIDR `10.A.0.0/16` and VPC B with CIDR `10.B.0.0/16`.  I have VPC A and B peered and updated the route tables and from a server in `10.B.0.0/16` can ping a server in `10.A.0.0/16` and vice versa.

The applications on VPC A also use some IPs in the `192.168.0.0/16` range.  Not something I can easily change, but I need to be able to reach `192.168.0.0/16` on VPC A from VPC B.  VPC A is used for an older kubernetes cluster that uses project-calico. Worker nodes (ec2 instances) get IPs in the VPC CIDR block `10.A.0.0/16` but the calico networking is set with the cluster CIDR setting `192.168.0.0/16` and pod IPs on those worker nodes get assigned in that range. The newer cluster is an EKS cluster and pod IPs are assigned from the VPC's CIDR range, `10.B.0.0/16`. During the transition period I've got the two clusters' VPCs peered together.  There's a distributed Elixir application running and the pods form an Erlang cluster by reaching each other via their pod IP address.  With my current peering cluster A pods can reach both A and B pods, but cluster B pods can only reach B (due to the `192.168.0.0/16` IPs not being reachable.

I've tried adding `192.168.0.0/16` to the route table used for VPC B and setting the target of the peered connection. That does not work, I believe because `192.168.0.0/16` is not in the CIDR block for VPC A.

I'm unable to add `192.168.0.0/16` as a secondary CIDR in VPC A because it is restricted. See [CIDR block association restrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#add-cidr-block-restrictions) and [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381126/how-do-we-allot-the-secondary-cidr-to-vpc-in-aws).  I understand it is restricted, but why is it restricted?  RFC1918 doesn't seem to say anything against using more than one of the private address spaces.

I've also tried making a Transit Gateway, attaching both VPCs, and adding a static route to the Transit Gateway Route Table for `192.168.0.0/16` that targets the VPC A attachment.  But still cannot reach that range from within VPC B.

##### Route Table

The route table for the private subnet for VPC A

```
10.A.0.0/16    local
10.B.0.0/16    pcx-[VPC A - VPC B peering connection]
0.0.0.0/0      nat-[gateway for cluster A]
```

Route table for the private subnet for VPC B

```
10.B.0.0/16    local
10.A.0.0/16    pcx-[VPC A - VPC B peering connection]
192.168.0.0/16 pcx-[VPC A - VPC B peering connection]
0.0.0.0/0      nat-[gateway for cluster B]
```

This does not work, of course, because `192.168.0.0/16` is not in VPC A's CIDR block, nor can it be added.

If I get a shell going on a Node A I can ping a `192.168...` pod and I can ping a `10.B.0.0` pod.  But from a shell on Node B I can only ping a `10.B.0.0` pod.

**Is there another way to peer to both `10.0.0.0/8` and `192.168.0.0/16` CIDR blocks on the same VPC?**